# How to capture screen snippets and share it with users

Tags: user-interface, screen-scraping

Sometimes you might like a screen snippet in a certain web page, you would ideally would want to capture that and probably add some notes to a portion of the user interface. What kind of tools are available to capture this information and share it with other users.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried [snagit](http://www.techsmith.com/screen-capture.asp)? yo can customize it to get different kind of capture with each hot key.

for example, i use

- Ctrl + PrintScreen = Region to ImgEditor
- Ctrl + Alt + PrintScreen = Region to Clipboard
- Ctrl + Shift + PrintScreen = FullScreen to File

you can also capture a Window, a Menu, a Scrolling Window (long web page), and it has a lot of other features that i haven't explored yet

Comment: You can also easily add callouts and crop or draw on the image.  Camtadia Studio from the same site is great for capturing videos tje same way and can make animated GIFs.

Answer (score 1):

My workplace uses [PrintKey](http://download.cnet.com/PrintKey-Pro/3000-2191_4-10820437.html), which stays resident in the system tray until you press the print screen button, which brings up the user interface, allowing you to drag a rectangle to capture, save, and print.

At home, I use the print screen button, when copies the desktop in to the clipboard, and I paste it in to MS Paint.

Answer (score 0):

I find the Snipping Tool in Windows 7 great to capture windows and screen areas. But you might be using a different OS.

Answer (score 0):

http://snapplr.com - but I am biased as I am one of the developers ;) (Mac OS X only)